# Consecutive numbers list where each number repeats

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How can I create a list of consecutive numbers where each number repeats N times, for example:

```
list = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another idea, without any need for other packages or sums:

```
[x//N for x in range((M+1)*N)]
```

Where `N` is your number of repeats and `M` is the maximum value to repeat. E.g.

```
N = 3
M = 5
[x//N for x in range((M+1)*N)]
```

yields

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

My first instinct is to get some functional help from the funcy package. If `N` is the number of times to repeat each value, and `M` is the maximum value to repeat, then you can do

```
import funcy as fp

fp.flatten(fp.repeat(i, N) for i in range(M + 1))
```

This will return a generator, so to get the array you can just call `list()` around it

Comment: This will return generator in python 3, but list in python 2. To get iterator in python 2 use `iflatten()`.

Answer (score 0):

`sum([[i]*n for i in range(0,x)], [])`

Comment: `sum` is **very** slow for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code is the simplest version I can think of. 
It’s a bit dirty and long, but it gets the job done.

In my opinion, it’s easier to comprehend.

```
def mklist(s, n):
    l = []  # An empty list that will contain the list of elements
            # and their duplicates.

    for i in range(s):     # We iterate from 0 to s
        for j in range(n): # and appending each element (i) to l n times.
            l.append(i)

    return l  # Finally we return the list.
```

If you run the code …:

```
print mklist(10, 2)
```

[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]

```
print mklist(5, 3)
```

[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4

Another version a little neater, with list comprehension.
But uhmmm… We have to sort it though.

```
def mklist2(s, n):            
    return sorted([l  for l in range(s) * n])
```

Running that version will give the following results.

```
print mklist2(5, 3)
```

Raw    : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Sorted: [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]